# Apache Spark. Как преобразовать значения свойств json объекта при помощи TF-IDF?

Tags: алгоритм, json, преобразование, cluster, apache-spark

Есть файл `.json` с данными вида:

```
{
    "hits": {
        "total": 213205,
        "hits": [{
            "_source": {
                "home_town": "Санкт-Петербург",
                "first_name": "Ваня",
                "schools": [],
                "city": 2,
                "relation": 0,
                "career": [],
                "relatives": [{
                    "type": "sibling",
                    "uid": 49097274
                }, {
                    "type": "sibling",
                    "uid": 4602569
                }, {
                    "type": "sibling",
                    "uid": 2613274
                }, {
                    "type": "sibling",
                    "uid": 56078646
                }],
                "quotes": "",
                "university_name": "ПГУПС Императора Александра I",
                "domain": "id61637701",
                "activities": "",
                "music": "",
                "site": "",
                "followers_count": 88,
                "tv": "",
                "country": 1,
                "bdate": "4.8.1996",
                "wall_comments": 1,
                "sex": 2,
                "movies": "",
                "personal": {
                    "life_main": 7,
                    "people_main": 2,
                    "political": 6,
                    "religion": "Буддизм"
                },
                "faculty_name": "",
                "last_name": "Иванов",
                "status": "*ils furent des anges comme vous*",
                "interests": "",
                "university": 31,
                "books": "",
                "uid": 61637701,
                "has_photo": 1,
                "universities": [{
                    "city": 2,
                    "country": 1,
                    "id": 31,
                    "name": "ПГУПС императора Александра I"
                }],
                "occupation": {
                    "id": 31,
                    "name": "ПГУПС Императора Александра I",
                    "type": "university"
                },
                "about": "",
                "military": [],
                "games": "",
                "last_seen": {
                    "platform": 4,
                    "time": 1464678438
                },
                "graduation": 0,
                "faculty": 0,
                "@version": "1",
                "@timestamp": "2016-05-31T07:18:36.418Z"
            }
        }, {
            "_source": {
                "home_town": "",
                "first_name": "Константин",
                "schools": [],
                "city": 2,
                "relation": 0,
                "career": [],
                "relatives": [{
                    "type": "sibling",
                    "uid": 49827057
                }],
                "quotes": "",
                "university_name": "",
                "domain": "krait_on",
                "activities": "",
                "music": "",
                "site": "no",
                "home_phone": "no",
                "followers_count": 87,
                "skype": "todo_here",
                "tv": "",
                "country": 1,
                "bdate": "7.3",
                "wall_comments": 0,
                "sex": 2,
                "movies": "",
                "personal": {
                    "inspired_by": "Музыка",
                    "life_main": 5,
                    "langs": ["English", "Русский"],
                    "smoking": 4,
                    "religion": "Буддизм",
                    "alcohol": 4
                },
                "faculty_name": "",
                "last_name": "Вострецов",
                "status": "",
                "interests": "",
                "university": 0,
                "books": "",
                "uid": 156616695,
                "has_photo": 1,
                "universities": [],
                "about": "",
                "military": [{
                    "country_id": 1,
                    "unit": "15010",
                    "unit_id": 7792
                }],
                "games": "",
                "last_seen": {
                    "platform": 7,
                    "time": 1464641428
                },
                "graduation": 0,
                "faculty": 0,
                "@version": "1",
                "@timestamp": "2016-05-31T07:19:03.596Z"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Как вытащить эти значения свойств каждого объекта в Apache Sparkе и преобразовать их к виду:

```
1000;3.0,3.0
1001;10.1,3.2
1003;2.7,2.7
1004;5.0,5.0
1005;13.1,2.2
1006;12.7,12.7
```

Я думаю нужно использовать TF-IDf. Просто, далее предполагается классифицировать и кластеризовыать данные. А может как-то еще проще можно это проделать, используя что-нибудь другое?

И есть ли какие-нибудь примеры кода?

Comment: Хотелось бы понять, какие именно значения необходимо вытащить?

Comment: С учетом того, что данные явно вытащены из эластика, проще это сделать с его помощью.